# intl.numberFormat() vs manual formatting + toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, performance, number-formatting

i have a requirement to display some currency values which will be around 50+ per page.
so i was confused on which will be better in performance i have 2 options :

one is to create function with below code and call it

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-In',{style : 'currency',
currency :CURRENCY_VARIABLE}).format(amount)
```

and the second one is  i have to call a function to get Currency symbol as i have an long JSON file with country,currency name and symbols so my second method will be

```
`${getCurrencySymbol(CURRENCY_VARIABLE)} 

 ${Math.abs(amount).toLocaleString('en-IN', 
 { minimumFractionDigits: 2,})}`,
```

which is better to use?

Comment: Create your formatter only once and reuse it `const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(...` and then in your loop `value = formatter.format(amount)`. But from a small test I get 10000 operations in 0.26ms, which means your 50 calls would theoretically take about 0.0013ms I doubt that's really a bottleneck in your code, so please chose the easiest to read and to maintain.

Comment: Thank you.. so whats ur opinion ? Are u saying that format using Intl is better than manually fetch currency from local obj and use toLocaleString

Comment: I am saying that it's your call. I don't know the team you'll be working with on this project. Ask **their** opinion not the one of an Internet stranger like myself.